# Facing issue in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I changed my property color in android studio to white, how can I revert it ?

[image: Check the image here]

Comment: which color? IDE theme color

Comment: No not the theme of a-studio. Under property we have a option named as color on which i wrote #FFFFFF due to which all options under 'property' are not visible it appears like a blank white area  .

Answer (score 0):

Go to Files-> Settings-> under Appearance & Behavior click Appearance-> on right side there is UI options, click the options beside Theme and then you can change to any theme you want.